# Looking for a better alternative to linklabels

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Please see the two long linklabels below (please ignore the black lines above)
Linklabels' length is made dynamically during runtime, and as seen, could be that it's too long and overlapping other text we have (there is another text where you see 'Differences').

[image]

My questions are:

a) Can I limit the maximum length of a linklabel?

b) Is that possible to use a scrollbar with a linklabel (or any similar control) in case that it's too long? e.g. setting it to 200 pixels, and in case it's longer, the user has to scroll the horizontal scroller and see end of the text.

I'm using VB.NET on Visual Studio 2008

THANK YOU

Comment: Nice to know you're using VB, but we also need to know where you are programming it in: I'm assuming you are working in winforms?

Comment: LinkLabel already supports this well, no code required.  In the designer, set its AutoSize property to False and AutoEllipsis property to True.  Note the tooltip you get at runtime.  Play around some more with properties and see what effect they have, that can save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a) Can I limit the maximum length of a linklabel?"

The label and the link is stored separately so you could use SubString to limit the length of your label to a specific amount of characters.

b) Is that possible to use a scrollbar with a linklabel (or any similar control) in case that it's too long? e.g. setting it to 200 pixels, and in case it's longer, the user has to scroll the horizontal scroller and see end of the text.

You could create a user control, set Autoscroll to true, put a linklabel inside the user control. Making sure that there is enough space below the label for a scrollbar, in case it becomes visible as your link label starts hanging out of the containing user control.

Hope this helps,
Gabor

Answer (score 1):

Will this help...However the code is for Labels

```
Private Sub InitializeLabel()
Me.Label1 = New Label
Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
Me.Label1.Name = "Label1" 
Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0

' Set the label to a small size, but set the AutoSize property  
' to true. The label will adjust its length so all the text 
' is visible, however if the label is wider than the form, 
' the entire label will not be visible. 
Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
Me.Label1.AutoSize = True 
Me.Label1.Text = "The text in this label is longer than the set size." 

End Sub
```